# How strictly should we judge low quality bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, bounty, question-quality

As of late I have encountered a couple of bounty questions that have been rather sub-par in their quality and I had some second thoughts about their legitimacy as a questions in and of themselves.

I guess that leads me to ask: **Should bounty questions be exempt / or at least judged with closed eyes on their quality, just because they are bounty questions?**

There have been multiple ones, but I'll use this as an example because it sprung up on my front page as the latest one:
[How to get a road path which can be travelled in 10 minutes from a location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572251/how-to-get-a-road-path-which-can-be-travelled-in-10-minutes-from-a-location)

[image]

Now I don't know about you folks, **but here I'd be strongly inclined to press the down-vote button, if the question was not appended with a bounty**. I'd actually maybe even consider flagging the question as too broad or possibly even as off-topic requesting tutorials, or other off-site resources.

> Let's pretend we're in a mod queue now and we didn't know there's a
>   bounty open with this question. Let's point out what is all wrong with
>   it. *My thought process would be something like this:*
>
> 1. The question desperately needs some formatting, at least some paragraphs on first look.
> 2. The title of the question could use some work
> 3. Grammar and syntactical errors aside, it's not very clear what the questioner actually wants to do. Maybe not 'unclear what you're asking
>      flag' level, but pretty close.
> 4. The question lacks any effort made, be it in the question itself, or worse yet, code of any of the previous efforts and what not.
> 5. In general, this question is more of a code request, than an actual question fit for Stack Overflow.
> 6. I'd definitely at least down-vote this question in a mod review, if not more.

I don't know how about you, but this seems to me like a recurring issue on our site, where people seem to put zero or minimal effort into solving their question, add a small extra bounty to the question of insignificant *(and meaningless)* 50 karma and we actually eat it all up, in many cases producing actually high quality answers!

**What is SO's stance on bounty questions like this? Shouldn't there be stricter rules enforced?** Even the hive mind seems to be okay with it, because **I don't see any down-votes cast** on the question by the populace, **nor any comments or flags raised.**

---

**Appendix:**

Some other questions (grabbed straight from the top of bounty page with minimal searching), which are at the very least debatable in their quality if not outright breaking one if not multiple SO rules.

I'm not listing them here for any particular reason, my only point is how easy is to find them and how flooded and unmoderated the bounty page appears to me.

[How to open icloud app (Files) programatically in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518943/how-to-open-icloud-app-files-programatically-in-swift)
[Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517005/unable-to-get-provider-com-crashlytics-android-crashlyticsinitprovider)
[Make SAP Report available via RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535306/make-sap-report-available-via-rfc)
[SSL IOWebSocketChannel with self signed cert using flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562727/ssl-iowebsocketchannel-with-self-signed-cert-using-flutter)
[Getting random crashes while pushing to another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553267/getting-random-crashes-while-pushing-to-another-view-controller)
[Allow access of application based on ip, or proxy network coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572920/allow-access-of-application-based-on-ip-or-proxy-network-coverage)

*and I could go on for ages...*

And keep in mind, this is literally grabbed straight from the front page. If I did bit more scraping of the barrel, I could easily find much worse. *I don't know, maybe I just have too critical and strict a view...?*

Comment: @pnuts While I wholeheartedly agree with the point you're making, on the other hand I do believe  there is an argument to be made, that there needs to be a line drawn somewhere when it comes to quality control. I'm not worried for my time that I'm going to delegate myself. I am however worried about the time of others and potential loophole in the system, that turns low quality "code for hire requests" into a legitimate SO questions for "50-100 e-points"

Comment: Why would a bounty *stop* you from downvoting?

Comment: If someone really wants an answer to their low-quality question, they should improve the question instead of adding a bounty; it'll greatly improve their chances of getting a decent answer. You should tell them that in a comment. And feel free to downvote if they ignore your request for improvement.

Comment: It would not stop me, especially if I suspected that the bounty was a trade on the Ring-Puppet Rep Exchange.

Comment: @user2357112 Perhaps I should have worded myself better there. It doesn't necessarily stop me from downvoting per se. But it seems that the general consensus amongst fellow community members is to turn a bit of a blind eye towards the bounty questions.

Comment: Note that some bounty may be a means of transferring reputation points between accounts (controlled by the same person) as a way to retain reputation points when the voting rings (and the user accounts) are destroyed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm kind of split on this being a duplicate. While there are some undoubtable similarities between the two posts, I feel like the 'original' question classifies more to a what *"What exactly shoud we do with a low quality bounty question"* while mine is more skewed towards the *What could be classified as low quality bounty question and SO's stance*. I  believe there is a reasonable discussion to be had regarding this, perhaps now more than before given the circumstances have changed since 2016. If however none stems from this, I'm more than happy tagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: maybe you're right; It's a _possible_ duplicate. I wanted to ask something like that because, like you, I think that you cannot post crap questions & put a bounty on them so they're acceptable & answered, I had done my research.

Comment: The most important thing is that the asker does not feel unwelcome. Especially since a bounty has been added the they deserve an answer. They are paying in rep. They should not go away disappointed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please tell me that is sarcasm.

Comment: It is just a basic misconception that the bounty page would be the home for good questions.  By definition it is not, that is where stuff that failed the normal Q+A process ends up.  Multiple reasons for it to fail, ideally it is a problem that is just plain hard to solve and requires more views to get lucky.  A ideal that is rarely reached, much more typical is that it is question is very poorly documented and managed to dodge enough close votes.  Like this one did, the [gis] tag community is completely dead and the title ensured that nobody from the [postgresql] community looked at it.